# Show $X$ is a H-space?

Tags: homotopy-theory, group-cohomology

Let $Y$ be a H-space and suppose $X$ is a pointed retract of $Y$ with continuous pointed maps $s,r$.

My thinking so far;

If Y is a H-space then there is a map $m:Y$x$Y \rightarrow Y$ such that $m$ composed with the inclusion map is homotopic to the identity. So we need an $n$ that does the same but for maps on $X$. So if $n=r \circ m \circ s$x$s$ then I have a map that satisfies the condition for a H-space so I am done? Or do i need to somehow show that this composed with the inclusion map is the identity on $X$?

Comment: By definition, that $n$ satisfies the conditions for an H-space is exactly that $n$ composed with each $X\to X\times X$ given by $x\mapsto (x,*)$ and $x\mapsto (*,x)$ gives you a map homotopic to the identity, so that is all you need to show.

Comment: I am not sure how I would go about showing that tho? As i know very little about each map?

Comment: Hint: let $H:Y\times I\to Y$ be a homotopy that shows $Y\to Y\times Y\xrightarrow{m} Y$ is homotopic to the identity, where $Y\to Y\times Y$ is $y\mapsto (*,y)$. Can you use this to show the H-space property for your map $n$?